# Blank line before doctype

Tags: themes, headers

I have a frustrating problem. In the page source, the first line is blank, which causes issues in some browsers.

These are the steps I've taken to try to fix the problem:

- Gone back to twentythirteen theme
- renamed plugins folder to oldplugins. Checked in admin and they are all deactivated
- Made sure there is nothing outside of the php in index.php, header.php
- cleared out htdoc htaccess

I'm at a loss!

Comment: Did you compare all WordPress files to a fresh download if anything differs?

Comment: There's a file called sunrise.php in wp-content.  That had an empty line after the closing php so I thought removing that would solve it.  It didn't. Interestingly, I put '123' directly after the closing php and that shows up on line 1 of the source, instead of the blank line.

Comment: Found it! there was a blank line in wp-config :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, there was a carriage return after the closing php tag in wp-config.

Comment: You don't need to close php tags. What WordPress version are you using? `wp-config.php` does not have a closing tag by default.

Comment: 3.8.1. It's probably me that has put one in by mistake in the past, including the offending blank line. Its a learning curve ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered, but in case anyone else runs into it:
if there is a ?>\n in any of the **included** files of the theme's functions.php or in functions.php itself at the very bottom, that can cause it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Great current answers, but worth noting: My extra line breaks were hidden away in `/wp-content/mu-plugins/custom-post-types.php` where I had setup some Custom Post Types. Once I deleted all characters after the closing `?>` and refreshed the front-end, everything works great!

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the step, for each, check if there is not space or empty line before  :

- in the root : check wp-config
- in your child theme : check functions.php, index.php, header.php
- in your parent theme : check   functions.php, index.php, header.php

Next :  deactivate all plugins : check if there is not space or empty line in the html source. If yes, activate your plugins one by one.

Next : Check your functions.php and all the included files. For each, check it.